# Python selenium click a button that loads data in a loop

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have a page that has a see more or load more button at the end, and when you click the button it takes around seconds to load more data. I used the following code with a for loop to click this button until all data loads:

```
counter = 0
while True:
    print(counter, end=":")
    try:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(1)
        see_more_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@class="ia-e-button ia-e-button--primary ia-m-searchresults-btn-load"]')
        see_more_btn.click()
        counter += 1
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
```

but this gives me after running for less than 10 loops this error:

Message: stale element reference: stale element not found

so I searched and found that I should use explicit wait in selenium so I created this code:

```
counter = 0
while True:
    print(counter, end=":")
    try:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        see_more_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='ia-e-button ia-e-button--primary ia-m-searchresults-btn-load']")))
        see_more_btn.click()
        counter += 1
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
```

But I still get the same error but after more iterations -not too many-
Note: I found that when it gives this error the driver keeps clicking the button as if it take the order before break and didn't have enough time to do all of clicks

Comment: Please add more details to the post such as the URL. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example